# Capture ui dragged outside its parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some divs inside a parent div. Is there any way I can detect if one of the inside div are dragged outside its parent?

This prevents #blue go outside #parent. What I try is let it out but have an alert when this happens:
    { containment: "#parent", scroll: false }

JQUERY UI:

```
$( ".blue" ).draggable(

        // { containment: "#parent", scroll: false }, 
        { drag: function( event, ui ) { 
            if(   ) { 
                // alert( "something" );    
            }
        }

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px; height:300px;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.blue { 
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px; height:30px;
    margin:10px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple *(but rather **heavyweight**!)* solution is to make the entire container `droppable`, since the droppable widget supports this out-of-the-box:

```
$("#parent").droppable({
    accept: ".blue",
    out: function() {
        alert( "something" );
    }
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LL3g80r3/

Comment: How can I select only the div I drag? in this case $(this) is #parent. I try to do something like $(this).fadeOut("slow"); (only the blue I drag)

Comment: Use `ui.draggable` (where `ui` is the second argument to the event handler) ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out (the documentation is incomplete; when the object you're dragging is a draggable, the `ui.draggable` will be there)